# Double click on image to activate checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have one image and two checkboxes.

When you click once on the image the first checkbox gets activated and now I want to activate the second checkbox when you click a second time on the image.

Is this possible?

Here is an example of the code I've used to activate the first checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/pAYFa/1/?

```
<label for="img1"><img class="img" src="image.jpg"/></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="img1" />
```

Comment: Why double click instead of single click?

Comment: Because the single click is already activating one checkbox, so it will need to be a second click to activate the other one. I don't want the first click to activate both checkbox. It could be that the person owns the book but he did not read it.

Comment: If you double click with what you have already, a user would be unchecking and then checking the checkbox. Also how will the user know they have to do this? This isn't a very good approach from a usability perspective. I'd recommend a different approach with more form elements or something.

Comment: You're probably right but somehow I did not figure another approach so far. Right now my page is the way you mentioned: someone clicks on the image and the first checkbox gets activated, if he clicks again then the first checkbox is disactivated. And to activate the second checkbox, one has to click on it but I thought it would be nicer to deal with the image only since the checkbox is small (mostly on tablets or smartphones)

Comment: Also note, the id of the checkbox and the image are the same. It's a good practice to keep the id's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an onclick event to the image, and use it to call a javascript function.  Within that, check to see if the first checkbox is checked, and if it is, check the second one.
Info on onclick: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" onclick="checkthebox()">
```

Pseudocode for the function:

```
function checkthebox(){
if(document.form.one.checked == false) {
document.form.one.checked = true;
}
else document.form.two.checked = true;
}
```

You will need to edit the code so that the function targets your actual checkboxes, and not these named "one" and "two"

Comment: That works fine and answer my original question. Now there is one thing I had not though off... What if the person click on it because he actually wants to uncheck. I guess there should be something like elseif one.checked and two.checked = true then make it false. Could you edit the above code for something like that to happen?

Comment: You probably should just let your users click the checkboxes instead of the images.  It will be much less confusing and you won't have to deal with complex script.  Plus - what if they read the book but they don't own it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this event it will work.

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick(function() { 
    alert( "Handler for .dblclick() called." ); 
});
```